# Android Studio : .sfb file not showing in Viewer

Tags: android-studio, arcore, sceneform

I use sceneform and ARCore in my project. I have got a sfb file (I know that its content is correct), but the Viewer window is black and doesn't show anything (I should see my 3D model)

Any idea how to solve this problem ?

Comment: could you solve the problem? I have the same issue wirh View

Comment: I don't remember... :( Perhaps it was a question of folder. I also wonder if the preview didn't work but it worked when the app was launched. Good luck :)